# What happens when I send a char array into a function whose input parameter is a string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I know it will work. I am more interested of what conversion happens if I send it. Is it better for me to change the parameter to  `char*` and then converted it myself using `to_String?` Or is this fine as it is, in the term of creating unexpected errors in the long run ?

Comment: It is OK but inefficient as the char array must be copied into the `std::string` object. If you don't need to modify the parameter and your compiler supports C++17, you should use `std::string_view` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` has a constructor which will take care of this case:

```
string (const char* s);
```

that makes the following work:

```
char *s = "Hello, World!";
std::string str(s);
```

As soon as `s` is not `NULL` not long run errors will take place.

[docs here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

Answer (score 1):

since `std::string` has a constructor that accepts `const char*` the compiler is smart enough to use it and allow you to pass `const char*` as an `std::string` argument. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Answer (score 0):

In c++, when a type T has a constructor that takes a single parameter of type U (e.g. T::T(U)) then the compiler will allow the code to implicitly convert from type U to type T.

Consider the following code

```
struct U
{
    //etc.
}

struct T
{
    T(U obj);
    //etc.
}

my_func(T param);

int main()
{
    U u;

    my_func(u);
}
```

When the compiler gets to "my_func(u)" and sees that my_func expects a parameter of type T, it looks at the constructors for T. When it sees the constructor "T(U obj);", it inserts it in-place in the function call like so:

```
//...
int main()
{
    U u;

    my_func(T(u));
}
```

It is important to note that this is done *completely silently*, which can lead to some difficult debugging if it is done on accident as opposed to intentionally.